# Create a new column with date based on 3 other columns (year, month, day)

Tags: sql, qsqldatabase

Is there anyway to join 3 columns to create a new column with the date value

I have a column name
Month
Day
Year 
and I need to join them and show the date result of the values form those columns 
[image]

Comment: `void QDate::getDate(int *year, int *month, int *day) const` looks promissing..... (see: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#getDate )

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using concatenation and casting:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(dia, '-', mes, '-', ano) AS Date)
FROM s
```